# Error while making webservice call

Tags: java, apache-axis, webservices-client

I am accessing a webservice exposed by some other guy as a client using `axis2` and I     have made a wrapper method for abcStub .java (Stub java file made by  running some batch) and tried to instantiate the Stub file inside the wrapper java file. But i get following errors:

```
    INFO: ERROR org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction  - Dispatch[/remittanceTransaction] to method 'remTransApprove' returned an exception
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.neethi.PolicyEngine.getPolicy(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/apache/neethi/Policy;
    at org.tempuri.MIRSRemittanceServicesStub.getPolicy(MIRSRemittanceServicesStub.java:3558)
    at org.tempuri.MIRSRemittanceServicesStub.populateAxisService(MIRSRemittanceServicesStub.java:57)
    at org.tempuri.MIRSRemittanceServicesStub.(MIRSRemittanceServicesStub.java:268)
    at org.tempuri.MIRSRemittanceServicesStub.(MIRSRemittanceServicesStub.java:257)
    at org.tempuri.MIRSRemittanceServicesStub.(MIRSRemittanceServicesStub.java:305)
    INFO: g.tempuri.MIRSRemittanceServicesStub.(MIRSRemittanceServicesStub.java:297)
    at com.mtmrs.webservice.MIRSRemittanceTransactionManagerImpl.getAppDeclWrapper(MIRSRemittanceTransactionManagerImpl.java:201)
    at com.mtmrs.business.backoffice.impl.RemittanceTransactionManagerImpl.remTransApprove(RemittanceTransactionManagerImpl.java:1417)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at com.mtmrs.application.backoffice.action.RemittanceTransactionAction.remTransApprove(RemittanceTransactionAction.java:1409)
    ... 78 more
    INFO: WARN  org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor  - Unhandled Exception thrown: class javax.servlet.ServletException
     WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[action]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet action threw exception
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.neethi.PolicyEngine.getPolicy(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/apache/neethi/Policy;
    at org.tempuri.MIRSRemittanceServicesStub.getPolicy(MIRSRemittanceServicesStub.java:3558)
    at org.tempuri.MIRSRemittanceServicesStub.populateAxisService(MIRSRemittanceServicesStub.java:57)
    at org.tempuri.MIRSRemittanceServicesStub.(MIRSRemittanceServicesStub.java:268)
```

I think there must be problem with this

```
org.apache.neethi.PolicyEngine.getPolicy(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/apache/neethi/Policy;
```

or may be im wrong. Either way, dunno how to fix. Would be of much help if anyone knew of faced/solved this before.

I got this while making following call:

`public   String getAppDeclWrapper(String session, String parentAgent, String mirsTxnNo, String strReason, String isApprove, String modifiedBY){
         String returnString = null;

    try {`

```
         mtmrsLogger.info("Entering into Approve Decline procedure, Starting to send Status to MIRS");
               MIRSRemittanceServicesStub stub  = new MIRSRemittanceServicesStub(); //Error occurs at this line

               ApproveDecline approvedEcline = new ApproveDecline();
               ApproveDeclineResponse approveResponse =  new ApproveDeclineResponse();
               approvedEcline.setCParentAgent(parentAgent);
               approvedEcline.setMirsSession(session);
               approvedEcline.setModifiedBy(modifiedBY);
               approvedEcline.setRefNo(mirsTxnNo);
               approvedEcline.setStrReason(strReason);
               approvedEcline.setIsApprove(isApprove);
```

Comment: My guess is you have multiple versions (or invalid version) of PolicyEngine on your classpath. I think you are running inside a servlet engine. Try following code to determine where this version is stored and fix it: org.apache.neethi.PolicyEngine.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()

Comment: @UsmanSaleem Thanks Worked :) Problem with Neethi jar, had multiple version of that jar.

Comment: But niw i face SEVERE: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.

Comment: Has been fixed. I sent wrong parameters during the webservice call.

Comment: No issues, I will add my comment as an answer :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you have multiple versions (or invalid version) of PolicyEngine on your classpath. I think you are running inside a servlet engine. Try following code to determine where this version is stored and fix it:

```
org.apache.neethi.PolicyEngine.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLo‌​cation()
```